# Trying to delete all non letter parts of a word but this line deletes the whole word '"Have' from the tokenizer

Tags: java, arrays, stringtokenizer

```
while(tokenizer.hasMoreTokens()){
currentWord = tokenizer.nextToken();
String[] parts = currentWord.split(Pattern.quote("."));
String[] parts2 = parts[0].split(Pattern.quote(","));
String[] parts3 = parts2[0].split(Pattern.quote("?"));
String[] parts4 = parts3[0].split(Pattern.quote("\\.| "));
String[] parts5 = parts4[0].split("\"");
String[] parts6 = parts5[0].split(Pattern.quote(":"));

System.out.println(Arrays.toString(parts6));
```

I'm just trying to get this text to split properly, only issue right now is the word:

"Have

Also if someone could provide a solution that combines all this into one line that would be nice but I couldn't get that to work thanks

Comment: You don't show how you initialized the (legacy class) `StringTokenizer`

Comment: Can you provide a full example of input and the output you're expecting? That 7-level split doesn't seem very efficient or maintainable.

Comment: for( ; ; ){
                    currentString = asciiFile.readString();
                    StringTokenizer tokenizer = new StringTokenizer(currentString);

Comment: And the input right now is "Have

outputting to [ ]

Comment: That's not how you use a `StringTokenizer` (not that you should be using it at all). Are you saying your file contains *"Have outputting to [ ]*?

Comment: no the input is "Have

and this outputs to [ ]

all other words output normally
word. to [word]

back?" to [back]

Comment: Please show an example of your String you are trying to split.

Comment: Losing my identity, wondering, "Have I gone insane?"

this is the string it has trouble with, u can see it's because of the , and " in the same area

Comment: *no the input is "Have and this outputs to [ ] all other words output normally word. to [word] back?"* And what output are you hoping for?

Comment: I'm hoping for , "Have to output to [Have]

Comment: what are some examples of input and expected output?

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

The \ is to escape the ", and the "\\" are to escape the regex special characters "." & "?". We are replacing any of these .,":? with an empty string.

```
    while(tokenizer.hasMoreTokens()){
        currentWord = tokenizer.nextToken();
        final String cleanWord = currentWord.replaceAll("[\\.,\":\\?]", "");
        System.out.println(cleanWord);
    }
```

Comment: If this is the correct answer to your question please accept it.

Answer (score 1):

There are specialized classes in the API to parse words out of text. Here is one such:

```
import java.text.BreakIterator;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.stream.Stream;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Paths;

public class WordCollector {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            List<String> words = WordCollector.getWords(Files.lines(Paths.get(args[0])));
            System.out.println(words);
        } catch (Throwable t) {
            t.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static List<String> getWords(Stream<String> lines) {
        List<String> result = new ArrayList<>();
        BreakIterator boundary = BreakIterator.getWordInstance();
        lines.forEach(line -> {
            boundary.setText(line);

            int start = boundary.first();
            for (int end = boundary.next(); end != BreakIterator.DONE; start = end, end = boundary.next()) {
                String candidate = line.substring(start, end).replaceAll("\\p{Punct}", "").trim();
                if (candidate.length() > 0) {
                    result.add(candidate);
                }
            }
        });
        return result;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way if you want to split the line on non-letters.

`[^A-Za-z]+` split on one or more of non-letters

```
String line = "wordA, wordB; wordC;;; wordD, wordE!?+- !wordF??, !wordG!, wordH, wordI";
String[] words = line.split("[^A-Za-z]+");
for (String word : words) {
    System.out.println(word);
}
```

prints

```
wordA
wordB
wordC
wordD
wordE
wordF
wordG
wordH
wordI
```

On the other hand, if you want to remove those characters from a word, use a similar pattern. No need to specify the non-letter characters separately.

```
String word = "C:om!>{}.p*u**te,;rs";
word = word.replaceAll("[^A-Za-z]","");
System.out.println(word);
```

prints

```
Computers
```

Answer (score 0):

The code below shows how you can ignore all none alpha characters.

```
import java.io.*;
public class Main{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        int c = 0;
        while((c=System.in.read())!=-1)
           if (('a' <= c && c <= 'z') || ('A' <= c && c <='Z')
              System.out.print((char)c);
    }
}
```